# sh-script-mode: get [[ ... ]] pair expansion to automatically include whitespace?

Tags: yasnippet, bash, zsh, pairing

Say you're coding a shell script and you want to write something like:

```
  if [[ "$out" =~ 'none' ]]; then
    return $err
  fi
```

If you're just typing it out and have any of the various electric/pair modules active, you'll likely get something like

```
if [[‸]]
```

(with the position of point indicated by `‸`).

In most programming languages, this is great, but in POSIX/Korn-family shells like Bash or Zsh, you pretty much *always* should have a space after the `[[` *and* before the `]]`.

Inserting this manually is a pain since you need a space before, and a space after, and still get the point back in the middle. I frequently have wild error messages the first time i test a script because one of those spaces is missing, or they both ended up before or after the double-brace contents.

Is there a good way to rectify this, so that, ideally, in `sh-script-mode`, typing `[[` would result in

```
[[ ‸ ]]
```

so the necessary space is there and the point is correctly positioned?

Ideally, the answer would also let me select a region and press `[[`, and just as I can already today surround the region with brackets, parens, etc. this way, I'd get the same, just with `[[ $region ]]` instead of `[[$region]]`. Also, it would be useful if the Zsh `(( ... ))` form would  act in the same way.

(Note that I specifically do *not* want this behavior for square brackets in general; they're too-frequently used in other contexts when one doesn't want extraneous spaces, and the use of the single-bracket `[ ... ]` test construct is generally less preferable to the double-bracket one.)

---

#### p.s.

I'm setting aside YAS snippets and such for the moment—they could clearly solve this problem in many cases, and I even already use them to create entire `if..elif..else..fi` blocks with built-in `[[ $0 ]]`-type positioning code. And so, for writing entirely *new* shell code, this problem isn't that big of a deal.

But this issue tends to arise when I'm modifying existing logic, rather than entering in entirely new conditionals. One of the most common ways one might need to fix a wayward conditional is to change a simple conditional into a test, so introducing the `[[ ... ]]` test into an existing conditional is a frequent task.

An acceptable answer, but one I've tried to avoid, would be to make `[[` a YAS snippet in its own right. The issue is that if I defined it such that invocation was `[[⇥` (`⇥` meaning the tab or other YAS invocation key), the doubling expansion will have already happened, so I'd have to have Elisp in the snippet to fix the characters *after* the snippet's environment, which is something of a pain.

Answer (score 3):

You could try [smartparens](https://github.com/Fuco1/smartparens). With the settings below:

Pressing <kbd>[</kbd> <kbd>SPC</kbd> becomes `[ | ]`
Pressing <kbd>[</kbd> <kbd>[</kbd> <kbd>SPC</kbd> becomes `[[ | ]]`
Selecting `foo` and pressing <kbd>[</kbd> becomes `[ foo ]`
Pressing <kbd>[</kbd> a second time becomes `[[ foo ]]`

```el
(require 'smartparens)
(smartparens-global-mode 1)
(show-paren-mode 1)

(defun sp-shell-insert-spaces (_id action _context)
  (when (eq action 'wrap)
    (save-excursion
      (goto-char (sp-get sp-last-wrapped-region :end-in))
      (unless (looking-at "]]")
        (insert " "))
      (goto-char (sp-get sp-last-wrapped-region :beg-in))
      (unless (looking-back "\\[\\[" nil)
        (insert " ")))))

(sp-with-modes 'sh-mode
  (sp-local-pair "[" "]" :actions '(wrap insert navigate) :post-handlers '(sp-shell-insert-spaces))
  (sp-local-pair "[ " " ]" :actions '(wrap insert navigate))
  (sp-local-pair "[[" "]]" :actions '(wrap insert navigate))
  (sp-local-pair "[[ " " ]]" :actions '(wrap insert navigate)))
```

The code to create a simple `if..fi` block would look something like this:

```el
(defun sp-shell-post-handler (id action _context)
  (when (eq action 'insert)
    (insert " ")
    (save-excursion
      (indent-according-to-mode)
      (newline))))

(sp-local-pair 'sh-mode "if" "fi"
           :when '(("TAB"))
           :unless '(sp-in-string-p sp-in-comment-p)
           :actions '(insert navigate)
           :post-handlers '(:add sp-shell-post-handler))
```

Comment: I like this, but I just noticed that my init file's `use-package` invocation of smartparens has `(progn
      (require 'smartparens-config)
  ;    (smartparens-global-mode 1)
      ))` (which in the comment will get confused, but the `smartparens-global-mode` line is commented out). Anywhere I run `C-h k <ret> ` _`{,(,[,',"`_, I get `self-insert`, so how can I determine if I'm actually _using_ smartparens, or something else, in sh-script-mode?

Comment: If you want smartparens enabled only in shell you have to add `smartparens-mode` to `sh-mode-hook`. You should see SP in the modeline. I think the self-insert-command result you're seeing is expected, even with sp enabled.

Comment: Sorry, I think I misstated my question... I'm not entirely sure the thing that's doubling my brackets and quotes _is_ smartparens. I know from my config variables that in my C# mode configuration it's `electric-pair-mode`. In sh-script-mode, if I output the entire list of minor modes active, smartparens, electric-pair, and autopair are all listed. So how can I find out what's being called when I hit a particular key if its binding is just `self-insert-command`?

Comment: Hm. I'm not sure. I suppose you could isolate sp by disabling the other modes. This would tell you if sp is doing its job if that's what you want to know.